# How to Speed Up Contract API CustomerID Search?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to search the existing Customers and return the CustomerID if it exists.  This is the code I'm using which works:

```
        var CustomerToFind = new Customer
            {
                MainContact = new Contact
                {
                    Email = new StringSearch { Value = emailIn }                            
                }
            };
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        //see if any results
        var result = (Customer)soapClient.Get(CustomerToFind);
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

However, I've finding it appears extremely slow to the point of being unusable.  For example on the DEMO dataset, on my i7-6700k @ 4GHz with 24gb ram and SSD running SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition locally a simple email search takes between 3-4seconds.  However on my production dataset with 10k Customer records, it takes over 60 seconds and times out.

Is this typical using Contract based soap?  Screen based soap seems much faster and almost instant.  If I perform a SQL select on the database tables in Microsoft Management Studio I can also return the result instantly.

Is there a better quick way to query if a Customer with email address = "test@test.com" exists and return the Customer ID?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: We're using latest v6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try using `GetList` instead of `Get`. It's better suited for "search for smth" scenarios.
2. When using `GetList`, depending on which endpoint you're using, there are two more optimizations. In `Default/5.30.001` endpoint there's a second parameter to `GetList` which you should set to `false`. In `Default/6.00.001` endpoint there's no second parameter but there is additional property in the entity itself, called `ReturnBehavior`. Either set it to `OnlySpecified` and then add `*Return` to required fields, like this:

   ```
   var CustomerToFind = new Customer
   {
     ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.OnlySpecified,
     CustomerID = new StringReturn(),
     MainContact = new Contact
     {
       Email = new StringSearch { Value = emailIn }
     }
   };
   ```

or set it to `OnlySystem` and then use `ID` on returned entity to request the full entity.

Comment: Great that works way faster!  ReturnBehavior = ReturnBehavior.OnlySpecified works well (minor typo in the answer).